# Workaround for "url that is not owned by the developer"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The idea is to set (No Country Redirect) version of google.com as default engine for search.

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "homepage": "https://www.google.com/?gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&gws_rd=cr",
    "search_provider": {
        "name": "Google NCR",
        "keyword": "google.com/ncr",
        "search_url": "https://www.google.com/search?q={searchTerms}&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr",
        "favicon_url": "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "is_default": true
    }
```

Resulting in this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyDVw.png)

Apparently I'm not allowed to use google.com cause I don't own it?!

Is there anyway to set the default omnibox engine to this? I just need to add this parameter to the request URL

```
&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr
```

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently I'm not allowed to use google.com cause I don't own it?!

Indeed. It has to be a verified item for you in the Google Search Console.

There's no direct workaround for it; you can't touch search settings otherwise.

---

An indirect workaround is making a custom domain under your control that redirects users to the requested search page instead. I wonder if that would work with Google's ToS..

Comment: Thats' fine, but maybe there's a way to redirect via JS and not manifest. i.e. appending `&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr` to the omnibox URL

Comment: Take a look at the `webRequest` API if you want to redirect in code (specifically, background page)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it all out. Extension is available: [Google & Youtube NCR](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-youtube-ncr/nljmbnpnemoenbogmdnakjjapcmpioep)